# How to save data when a program is closed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, save

I'm making an application in C#(.net 4.0 & VS2010) which should allow a user to make a profile for use that has info like 'profile name, which options are check-marked, location to save files to' sort of stuff, SO the system has a list of select able profiles, where the user can make one active, edit,add, or remove a profile. I'm curious what the best way to store these profiles would be so that if the software is closed profiles are saved, and upon opening it all are available and can still be used. I think saving each profile to a .txt would be inefficient and not very secure. I've never dealt with saving data in a program w/o it being .txt so any suggestions or advise to which methods work best, or are easiest to understand would help!

Answer (score 1):

I typically create XML files to store parameter fields that require saving.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

It works well enough when you've not got sensitive material and you need to get parameters back without much heavy parsing.

Comment: Great answer! I had been suggested to XML files, but didnt quite know if there was a better or more standard way. thanks again